# How to change Pie full donut to half donut in Highcharts?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to change the Highcharts Pie full donut to half donut. I have done in the same way they mentioned in http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-semi-circle but couldn't achieve it. Do i need to change JS file or do I need to change  any options in JS file? Can any one help me.

```
plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              distance: -50,
              style: {
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  color: 'white',
                  textShadow: '0px 1px 2px black'
              }
          },
          startAngle: -90,
          endAngle: 90,
          center: ['50%', '75%']
        }
      }
```

Comment: COuld you replicate your entire chart as live demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you watch the code of the example you can see a option that sets the initial and final angle of the pie, so you can customize it:

```
plotOptions: {
 pie: {
   startAngle: -90,
   endAngle: 90,
 }
},
```

Comment: I have edited my question with whatever options I have already tried. Can you tell me those are correct or not.

Comment: But still the same issue. I have already tried with those options. Can you guess what might be the issue?

Comment: Maybe it's something wrong in your data. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-semi-circle/